# WPF and EF6 - Unrecognized configuration section entityFramework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

**Environment**: `VS2019`, `.NET 4.8`, `EF 6`, `SQLite`, `WPF App (.NET Framework)`

I am following this [Microsoft official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database) to create a code-first app, called `WPF_EF6` using SQLite. With the configuration shown below, I am getting an error.

**Question**: what may I be missing here? And how can we resolve the issue? App compiles fine but throws this runtime error:

> ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section entityFramework. (C:\DotNet2019\WPF\WPF_EF6\bin\Debug\WPF_EF6.exe.Config line 22)

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)"
                 invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
                 description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)"
                 type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
                 description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
                 type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SqlLiteContext" 
             connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MySQLiteDb.sqlite" 
             providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
                      type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"
                      type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**MyDbContex.cs**:

```
namespace WPF_EF6.Model
{
    public class MyDbContex : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContex() : base("MySQLiteDb")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<MyObj> MyObjs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install `System.Data.SQLite.EF6` Nuget package, there was some changes in `App.config` that is missed right now. To be precise, your are missing `<configSections>` element.

Your `App.config` should start like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error on the same app posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62057557/1232087)

Comment: This looks the same as what I have successfully used in the past for MySQL.